# devenv.exe. Revert back to non-administrator mode

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I wanted all the programs in VS 2012 to run as administrator automatically . I found an answer by @TigerShark here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8 
i did this and it worked . Now I want to revert back to the old settings. How would I do that?

Pls help. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s already mentioned in [a comment over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8#comment28088948_12859334):

> This is an equivalent of adding registry entry with name `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` and value `RUNASADMIN` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`. *Removing the entry reverts the setting back.*

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Can u please tell me how to remove the entry, Because when I went to troubleshoot compatibility on devenv .exe, Run as administrator box is unchecked but still it runs as administrator always.

Comment: Well then perhaps you did something different. Please describe what happens when you launch Visual Studio: Does the UAC dialog pop up and ask you for confirmation to run it as admin?

Comment: I did :right-click devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot compatibility".

select "Troubleshoot program"
check "The program requires additional permissions"
click "Next", click "Test the program..."
wait for the program to launch
click "Next"
select "Yes, save these settings for this program"
click "Close"
 .When i open a visual studio program, it says "do u want to allow this program make changes in your computer". Also even after the VS program window is closed , i cannot delete some files, it says that devenv.exe is still using it.

Comment: Well that’s fine then. Windows 7 does not display Compatibility Wizard flags in the properties dialog. *You have to use `regedit`.* But locked files are entirely unrelated to this question. If that is your actual problem, please either delete this question or mark it as answered. Then, make a new question about your actual problem.